# What is involved in preparing a W2?

Tags: united-states, form-w-2

Every year my payroll manager (Gusto) spends the first 24 days or so "preparing" my W2 and 1099s. They're a digital company that has *all* the data in front of them to generate the W2 on day 1 of a new year. What exactly are they *doing* while they "prepare" this document?

I'm mostly curious about why it takes so long...I've even asked and never really received an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm mostly curious about why it takes so long...I've even asked and never really received an adequate answer.

The statutory deadline is January 31st. They don't have to take that long, I got one of my 1098s yesterday (Jan. 3rd).

So the explanation could be as simple as they're doing it so late because they are allowed to. What's the hurry? I would imagine they have some kind of audit and testing process to ensure all the data is correct and all the calculations match, some of it may probably need manual work. Or maybe they just wait for as long as they can just because they can. Who knows? More importantly - who cares?

Comment: I care because I'm curious? I know they're legally in the clear.

Comment: Ask the individual company. They may all have different reasons beyond "because they can". Or they may have no reason beyond "because they can". Either way, I don't think we can give you an answer that's worth the bits it's expressed in.